# What are the accepted hand signals for cyclists in the UK?

Tags: safety, regional, uk, signals

see also "[What are the accepted hand signals for cyclists in the US?"](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1282/what-are-the-accepted-hand-signals-for-cyclists-in-the-us)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From a UK government website I found the following document (linked from [a page](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/TravelAndTransport/Highwaycode/DG_069837) about the Highway Code for cyclists).

**[Signals to other road users](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/signals-to-other-road-users)** (scroll to the bottom for cyclist information)

Essentially there are three signals for cyclists:

- Left arm out - "I intend to move in to the left or turn left"
- Right arm out - "I intend to move out to the right or turn right"
- (Right) arm up and down - "I intend to slow down or stop" (very rarely if ever used...)

In reality you will find only the left and right signalling used by UK cyclists - any other gestures would not be understood by enough other road users to make them worthwhile.

Comment: As I said above, I don't think I've ever used (or ever seen anybody else use) the slowing down signal.

Comment: I expanded my answer to reflect our shared experiences :)

Comment: I didn't understand the slowing/braking signal until I saw this: [http://goo.gl/P1j3](http://goo.gl/P1j3)

Comment: In N america is seems that you use the arm on the traffic side bent to say you are turning the other way - because the view of the other arm is blocked. Of course no driver knows this so there isn't much point!

Comment: One extra tip: if you're just waving to somebody on the right-hand side, use your left arm, and vice-versa. That way, it's less likely that anyone will mistake your friendly wave for a signal. This applies when waving to your friends as well as when waving thank-yous to other road users.

Comment: I used to use the slow down signal, but nobody seems to understand it, so these days I find slowing down gradually enough for the guy behind you to react safely is a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

When I'm turning left I put my left arm straight out.

When I'm turning right I put my right arm straight out.

Then I do the Hokey Cokey.....sorry got a bit carried away there.

I vaguely remember from my Cycling Proficiency test that flapping your right arm up and down signals that you're stopping, but in the more than 30 years since I passed it I don't remember ever using it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the normal right, left signals, I also like to give little friendly waves to any drivers where they've demonstrated a rudimentary knowledge of the highway code, such as not turning across my path when I have right of way.

Comment: And a one-fingered "wave" when they demonstrate a lack of that rudimentary knowledge? ;-)

Comment: Two fingered, surely.

Answer (score 2):

I use all four official hand signals when cycling.  This is in the UK of course.

Turning left:  Left arm out.

Turning right:  Right arm out.

Slowing down or stopping: right arm out, palm down and waving clearly up and down.

Going straight across (for junctions):  Right arm bent out at the elbow with hand pointing up.

Answer (score 0):

In Canada, It's

Left Turn: Left arm straight out.

Right Turn: Left arm bent up at the elbow.

Stop/slow down: Left arm bent down at the elbow.

The right arm isn't used because it's harder for drivers to see.  I thought the rules were pretty universal.  But according to @Amos, they aren't.

Actually, In the UK, I assume it would be reversed to use the right arm, sing you ride on the left and side of the road.

Comment: The Highway Code does contain hand/arm signals which can be done just with your right arm for car drivers, but I can't remember whether cyclists can employ them too. I passed my driving test 24 years ago and I don't think I've looked  at a copy of the Highway Code since.